# Appropriate tag for civil-code (Napoleonic code, et al.)

Tags: support, tags

The [civil-legal-system](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/civil-legal-system) tag is described as:

> Civil law is a legal system based on a codified set of principles that serve as the primary source of law. Not to be confused with [civil law] claims, which will often fall under [common-law].

Is this the same as what I'd call "civil code", the non-common-law system used in Europe, Québec, Louisiana, etc.?

If so, the description should be more explicit about it (or changed to "civil-code").

If not, what *is* the appropriate tag for this?

(Also, the intended use of brackets in the description isn't obvious.)

---

**UPDATE:** I see that I'm not the only one misled by the [civil-law](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/civil-law) tag:

- [How large is the difference in the amount of reading needed to become familiar with the law in common vs civil law countries? - Law
  Stack Exchange](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/60149/how-large-is-the-difference-in-the-amount-of-reading-needed-to-become-familiar-w)
- [How can we reconcile the fact that common law, relative to civil law, give judges more power in interpreting law but less power in guiding trials? - Law Stack Exchange](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/60046/how-can-we-reconcile-the-fact-that-common-law-relative-to-civil-law-give-judge)

One is from three days ago, and the other from today.
I imagine that this is a very common occurrence, which someone must be continually cleaning up.

Even worse, people will naturally search for [common-law](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/common-law) [civil-law](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/civil-law) when they want to find questions about the relationship between Common Law and Civil Law, and they will fail to find most of the questions.

The [civil-law](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/civil-law) tag really is misleading.
"common-law" and "civil-law" look far too much like complementary tags, and it's unlikely that most people are going to notice that "civil-law" isn't what they think it is.

Comment: and *THAT*s why I prefer to speak of the legal system as *Code Civil*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This is the correct tag**

Napolianic law is one of the main strands of [civil-legal-system](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/civil-legal-system).

[image]

By Maximilian Dörrbecker (Chumwa) - Own work, usingWorld map by Canuckguy and othersUNESCO World Heritage map by NNWThe data sources are:University of Ottawa: JuriGlobe – World Legal Systems Research GroupWikipedia: List of national legal systemsEuropean legal systems map by Ain92 and others (which seems to be based on this map by C.Löser and others)World legal systems map by Robinkissac, CC BY-SA 2.5, https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=40154967

I've edited the Tag info.